# Ionic 3 - Bluetooth thermal printer

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, thermal-printer

I have developed an ionic 3 mobile app.
I have bought a thermal printer (Rongta RPP320 http://www.rongtatech.com/products-look-89.html).

I tried almost every solution in github repos and forum solutions but nothing.

I used this repo to connect via Ionic Native Bluetooth Serial.
https://github.com/razmans/ionicBluetoothPrint/blob/master/src/providers/print/print.ts

I can make a bluetooth connection but i wasnt able to send data to the printer.

I have replaced the simple string with some hex codes from ascii code i found reading native java android code.

I can start moving the thermal printer with this code

```
let printData = new Uint8Array(2);
printData[0] = 0x1B;//escape
printData[1] = 0x71;
```

And then trying to feed him with a letter

```
data = new Uint8Array(3);   
 data[0] = 0x0C;
 data[1] = 0x41;
 data[2] = 0x0C;
```

It seems i cant exactly understand how thing are working. 
The only thing this code do is to roll the paper out. It cant print a letter